# Can we create scatter plot with a single data line

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, line, scatter

I have sample data in dataframe as below

```
Header=['Date','EmpCount','DeptCount']

2009-01-01,100,200

print(df)

       Date  EmpCount  DeptCount  
0 2009-01-01      100         200
```

Can we generate Scatter plot(or any Line chart etc..) only with this one record.

I tried multiple approaches but i am getting

```
TypeError: no numeric data to plot
```

In X Axis: Dates

In Y Axis: Two dots one for Emp Count , and other one is for dept count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from @the-cauchy-criterion, try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

header=['Date','EmpCount','DeptCount']
df = pd.DataFrame([['2009-01-01',100,200]],columns=header)
b=df.set_index('Date')
ax = plt.plot(b, linewidth=3, markersize=10, marker='.')
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to plot the scatter plot?

Here's how to do it with pyplot.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

header=['Date','EmpCount','DeptCount']
df = pd.DataFrame([['2009-01-01',100,200]],columns=header)

plt.scatter(*df.iloc[0][1:])
plt.show()
```

iloc[0] gets the first entry, [1:] takes all the columns except the first and the * operator unpacks the arguments.

Comment: I missed to add 2 lines in my question. I am trying to achieve X axis with dates and Y axis with counts